# unable to fill dropdown control in partial view in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i want to fill dropdown control of partial view.

this is my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

    namespace HelpDeskSystem.Models
    {
        public class CategoryModel
        {
            public string CategoryId { get; set; }
            public string CategoryName { get; set; }
            public int frequency { get; set; }

         //   public virtual ICollection<SubcategoryModel> subCategory { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

This is my Controller

```
 public ActionResult categories()
        {
          List<CategoryModel> categoriesList = new List<CategoryModel>();
          return View(categoriesList);
         }
```

Assume that there are records in my **categorylist** object.

This is my main **view page**

```
@model IEnumerable<HelpDeskSystem.Models.CategoryModel>
@using HelpDeskSystem.Models

@using GridMvc.Html

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "categories";
    Layout = "~/Views/Admin/AdminMaster.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/css/admincss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="categoryheader">Manage Categories</div>


    <div class="table-responsive" style="width: 98%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr style="background-color: #d6e6ed;">
                    <td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid #d7d7d7; border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d7d7; width: 20px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;">C#</td>
                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid #d7d7d7; border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d7d7; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;">Name</td>
                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid #d7d7d7; border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d7d7; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;">Tickets</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="15" style="border: 1px solid #d7d7d7; font-family: Arial, font-size:12px; font-weight: bold;">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        No records found...<br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>



 @Html.Partial("Createcategories",new CategoryModel())
```

This is my Partial view:

```
@model HelpDeskSystem.Models.CategoryModel


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <!-- container -->


        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <!-- Article main content -->
                <article class="col-xs-12 maincontent">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p class="text-center text-muted">
                                    Add New Category

                                </p>
                                <hr>
                                <span style="color: red;">@ViewBag.message</span>


                                 <div class="top-margin">
                                    <label>Parent Category <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                  @*  @Html.TextBox("categoryName", null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtcategoryID" })*@
                                     @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.CategoryId,null, "Select Category", new { id = "ddlCategory"})
                                </div>

                                <div class="top-margin">
                                    <label>Category Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    @Html.TextBox("categoryName", null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtcategoryID" })
                                </div>




                                <hr>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-5 text-right">
                                        <button class="btn btn-action" name="btnCategory" type="submit">Create Category</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </article>
            </div>
        </div>

}
```

but it is throwing me error on this line:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.CategoryId,null, "Select Category", new { id = "ddlCategory"})
```

**There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'CategoryId'.**

**can anybody tell me how to fill dropdown in my partial view???**

**as i am beginner in mvc**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main view your model is @model IEnumerable but when you call the partial you are passing a new CategoryModel which by definition will be empty.  To get that data to pass straight through to the partial change your partial call to

```
@Html.Partial("Createcategories", model)
```

then you will need to change the model on your partial to

```
@model IEnumerable<HelpDeskSystem.Models.CategoryModel>
```

and your drop down would then be

```
@Html.DropDownList("Selected", Model)
```

since you are just passing the list in your don't have a variable to tie the selected value to for using the DropDownListFor

Generally you are not going to only pass a list to your main view and pass it straight through to the partial.  If you have more data you can add the list to a viewModel

```
 public class ViewModel
    {
        //other fields used on your main page
        public List<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
    }
```

then you would need to change your controller to populate the viewmodel and pass it to your view and change your main page model to be the viewmodel.  then you can change your partial call to be

```
    @Html.Partial("Createcategories", model.CategoryList)
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: thank u so much for ur help.it works.thank u once again